# Rendering html to pdf

Tags: php, laravel, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am new to Laravel. I want to convert my HTML page into PDF therefore I am using:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Now from my controller I am using the following code:

```
$data = $this->getdata();
$html = view('myview', [ 'data' => $data] )->render();

$pdf = \App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHtml($html);
return $pdf->inline();
```

When I dump or return the `$html` variable, it's giving the desire view on the browser but when I convert it its not giving that output. My HTML page is also using Bootstrap but I think after rendering its just a normal HTML string.
Can anyone tell what I am missing here?

I have also tried `$pdf->loadView()` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the loadView function.

Try this:

```
$data = $this->getdata();

$pdf = \App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('my.view', $data);
return $pdf->inline();
```

And print what's returned by the laodView to see if it get your view correctly.